# How to access multi-tenant data in Azure ? Single Tenant to Multi Tenant migration

Tags: azure, office365, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, multi-tenant

I have an client app (**deamon** service) which fetch messages from single tenant mailbox.

I use **client_credenatials** auth mechanism (certificate) to speak to registered app in Azure.

Graph permission to access mail is also given in Azure by admin, so there is **no user intervention for consent**.

```
token_url -https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}/oauth2/token
post request data  = {
        'resource': https://graph.microsoft.com/,
        'client_id': client_id,
        'client_assertion_type': 'urn:ietf:params:oauth:client-assertion-type:jwt-bearer',
        'client_assertion': assertion(),
        'grant_type': 'client_credentials'
    }
```

assertion value is rsa signed value of this header and payload

```
client_assertion_header = {
        'alg': 'RS256',
        'x5t': thumbprint,
    }       
client_assertion_payload = {
'sub': client_id,
'iss' : client_id,
'jti' : GUID,
'exp'  : ten_mins_from_now, 
'nbf' : now,
'aud' : token_url
```

}

For single tenant everything works perfect as i would be knowing tenant id 
(i explicitly set the tenant id in token url)

Now i need to convert this application to access mails of multi-tenant (more than one tenant) . User can be in tenant A, or Tenant B.

With respect to my client app i'll be knowing only user id (and not tenant id when i make call) in case of multi-tenant

Things to keep in mind

1. I am admin of both tenant.
2. There is no user intervention, consent should be given in Azure portal itself (cannot do based on user sign in).
3. I can use only **client_credentials** auth flow as client app runs as deamon service

I am not sure if my application belongs to multi-tenant catagory.
Can someone plese help me on how to proceed ?  Anything i can do in manifest file ? What model i can use ?

Comment: Your choice of multi-tenanted is valid as you want 1 app to handle data in a variety of tenants. Using the **client_credentials** flow means you can only sign into one tenant at a time. Do you know the tenant names you are wanting to access? Also have you already set up your multi-tenanted application?

Comment: *"With respect to my client app i'll be knowing only user id (and not tenant id when i make call) in case of multi-tenant"* I'm late to the party, but it seems like the simplest way forward would have been to lookup the tenant id given the user id, then proceed as you did with a single tenant.